# How to semver versioning documentation update?

Tags: documentation, versioning, semantic-versioning

I'm writing a REST API wrapper and committed an important documentation change. How should I handle this according to [semver](https://semver.org/)? Should I update my minor/patch version number or completely ignore the update since source code has not changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the documentation changes. It's likely that you have a patch level change, provided you didn't suddenly say something like "this bug isn't a feature you can rely on and will be fixed eventually". In other words, if you don't have a lot of customers depending on some previously undocumented feature, that is now obviously being labelled as a bug, then it's a patch. But you may want to treat it as a breaking change if the gist of the new documentation effectively changes the world for a large percentage of your clientele.

Usually, in such cases, you publish as a minor change with clearly labelled deprecation language in the documentation, then you publish a breaking change that removes the undocumented feature or bug, along with associated changes to documentation.

If none of that applies to your documentation changes, it's a patch level change.